# Batch Script to Shell Script

Tags: shell, batch-file

I have written a small **batch script** which copies files from the a folder and paste in other folder with delay of 10 seconds. I want to convert it to shell script, but not getting the way to do that.
Please help me. The below is the batch script that i use:

```
@echo off & setLocal EnableDELAYedExpansion

pushd "C:\Users\abc\Desktop\Test"
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b/a-d "leaderboard*.txt"') do (
copy "%%a" "C:\Users\abc\Desktop\Test\final\leaderboard.txt"
timeout 10
) 
popd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the sourcedir and targetdir to the one you want (not according to your code you always copy on the same file leaderboard.txt, if you want to keep the original name just remove "leaderboard.txt" and keep only "$targetdir"

```
sourcedir=<SOURCEDIR>
targetdir=<TARGETDIR>

for a in "$sourcedir"/leaderboard*.txt; do
    cp "$a" "$targetdir"/leaderboard.txt
    sleep 10
done
```

NB: This solution does not work if you have spaces in the name of the files you want to copy

Comment: This should work fine for filenames with spaces, as long as you keep quoting `$a`, `$sourcedir`, and `$targetdir`. Word-splitting takes place prior to pathname expansion.